# Can we combine two text fields in report

Tags: reporting, formula

Can we combine two text fields in report, I would like to build a bucket field with combination of two fields.Any other way a part from creating formula field in Object.

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce doesn't provide on the fly combining field values unless we create formula field getting values of those two text fields or we can create a third text field and which can be updated by workflow field update.

Now choice is yours.

Comment: If my answer solves your requirement then, please accept this so other members can find this useful.